# How do I make it possible to subtract and multiply in both directions in a class method

Tags: class, python-3.x, methods

So I am trying to do a program that can add, subtract and multiply volumes (which consist of a magnitude and a unit) I got `__add__` to work but `__rsub__` and `__mult__` I have not figured out how to make them work. I want to be able to do operations like `Volume * 2` or `2 * Volume`. Any advice on how to go about it would be greatly appreciated!

```
def __add__ (self, v2): #adds to magnitude using an int or another volume
    if Volume.is_valid(self):
        if isinstance(v2, Volume):
            if Volume.is_valid(v2): #check if V2 is valid
                if self.__units == v2.__units:
                    return Volume(self.__magnitude + v2.__magnitude, 
                                  self.__units)
                else:
                    if v2.__units == 'ml':
                        v3 = v2.customary()
                        return Volume(self.__magnitude + v3.__magnitude, 
                                      self.__units)
                    elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                        v3 = v2.__units
                        return Volume(self.__magnitude + v3.__magnitude, 
                                      self.__units)

        elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
            #create new Volume with same units as self
            v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
            return Volume(self.__magnitude + v3.__magnitude, self.__units)

def __radd__ (self, v2): #adds ability to do i.e. 2 + a
    return self.__add__(v2)

def __sub__ (self, v2): #same as __add__ but this subtracts
    if Volume.is_valid(self):
        if isinstance(v2, Volume):
            if Volume.is_valid(v2):
                if self.__units == v2.__units:
                    return Volume(self.__magnitude - v2.__magnitude, 
                                  self.__units)
                else:
                    if v2.__units == 'ml':
                        v3 = v2.customary()
                        return Volume(self.__magnitude - v3.__magnitude, 
                                      self.__units)
                    elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                        v3 = v2.__units
                        return Volume(self.__magnitude - v3.__magnitude, 
                                      self.__units)
        elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
            v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
            return Volume(self.__magnitude - v3.__magnitude, self.__units)

def __rsub__ (self, v2):
    return Volume(v2.__magnitude - self.__magnitude, self.__units)

def __mult__ (self, v2):#multiplies a volume by an int only (not other vol)
    if Volume.is_valid(self):
        if isinstance(v2, Volume):
            if Volume.is_valid(v2):
                if self.__units == v2.__units:
                    return Volume(self.__magnitude * v2.__magnitude, 
                                  self.__units)
                else:
                    if v2.__units == 'ml':
                        v3 = v2.customary()
                        return Volume(self.__magnitude * v3.__magnitude, 
                                      self.__units)
                    elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                        v3 = v2.__units
                        return Volume(self.__magnitude * v3.__magnitude, 
                                      self.__units)
        elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
            v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
            return Volume(self.__magnitude * v3.__magnitude, self.__units)
        #return Volume(self.__magnitude * v2, self.__units)

def __rmult__ (self, v2):
    return self.__mult__(v2)
```

Comment: def __init__ (self, m = 0, u = "ml"):
        self.__magnitude = m
        self.__units = u

Answer (score 1):

The magic method for multiplying is [`__mul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__mul__#emulating-numeric-types), not `__mult__`.

`__rsub__` doesn't appear to do nearly as much work is `__sub__`.  Perhaps something like:

```
def __rsub__(self, v2):
    return Volume(v2) - self
```

would be better.